# Drop Down Menu on Action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am working on an android application Menu with Action Bar, I want to put the dropdown menu in the action bar like the one present in Google Maps application. 
[image: Google Maps ActionBar]

Can somebody help me? How to achieve this Please point to some easy tutorial that I can follow.

Comment: Please check your question as answered or rephrase it if necessary.

Comment: Please check the Android documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Dropdown

Answer (score 11):

Add this to your activity onCreate() method:

```
// Adapter
SpinnerAdapter adapter =
        ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.actions,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

// Callback
OnNavigationListener callback = new OnNavigationListener() {

    String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.actions); // List items from res

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long id) {

        // Do stuff when navigation item is selected

        Log.d("NavigationItemSelected", items[position]); // Debug

        return true;

    }

};

// Action Bar
ActionBar actions = getActionBar();
actions.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
actions.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actions.setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, callback);
```

This example requires an array resource for the list items:

res/values/arrays.xml

```
<string-array name="actions">
    <item>Item 1</item>
    <item>Item 2</item>
    <item>Item 3</item>
</string-array>
```

Alternatively you could create your own adapter and layout extended from SpinnerAdapter to display more advanced or dynamic list items.

To make the activity onCreate code even neater you could also change your Activity to implement OnNavigationListener and add the override onNavigationItemSelected with the callback code. Then change "callback" to "this" in the setListNavigationCallbacks() method.

Please note you will need to target API 11+ for the action bar, otherwise you will need to add version checking or a support library.

Answer (score 1):

check this Link also it is helpful example [Example link](http://codebybrian.com/2012/12/06/google_maps_android_v2_sample.html)

```
GoogleMap map;

TextView txt;

String[] mapTypes={"Normal","Hybrid","Satellite","Terrain"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();

    txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

//to set map Type
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

//To set the marker on map on specific location using lat lag
    // latitude and longitude
    double latitude = 18.520430300000000000;
    double longitude = 73.856743699999920000;

    // create marker
    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("My Location");

    // change color to the marker icon
    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN));

    // adding marker
    map.addMarker(marker);

    // Create an array adapter to populate dropdownlist 
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, mapTypes);

    /** Enabling dropdown list navigation for the action bar */
    getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

    /** Defining Navigation listener */
    ActionBar.OnNavigationListener navigationListener=new ActionBar.OnNavigationListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "U Select : "+mapTypes[itemPosition], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (mapTypes[itemPosition].equals("Normal")) {
                map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            }
            else if (mapTypes[itemPosition].equals("Hybrid")) {
                map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            }
            else if (mapTypes[itemPosition].equals("Satellite")) {
                map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            }
            else if (mapTypes[itemPosition].equals("Terrain")) {
                map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    // Setting dropdown items and item navigation listener for the actionbar 
    getActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, navigationListener);

}
```