# Titanium Android - Share one Menu overall Windows

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, android-menu

I'd like to know if there is a nice way to create a NavGroup, like on iOS, to share one menu overall windows.

Let's say I have several windows which lead to other windows like this:

- Index
- - Places
- - - Place 1
- - - Place 2
- - - Place 3...
- - Galerie
- - - Galerie 1
- - - - Picture
- - Options
- - - Option 1
- - - Option 2

Everything above is a new window.

Now I want to navigate from Option 2, back to Places, from Picture to Options and vice versa, etc. Everything done over the Android Menu.

Do I need to attach the menu on the activity of every Window? Or is there a nicer way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the ActionBar? I've never used Titanium but this sounds like what you are talking about. you can create a dropdown menu that stays with all windows/fragments sortof like the G+ app.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Dropdown

[Drop Down Menu on Action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376101/drop-down-menu-on-action-bar)

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android.ActionBar

Comment: Yes I am using the ActionBar.
My question is, do I need to initialize the Menu on every new activity? is this the default behaviour?
When I look at the Play Store, you don't get a new Window, its just navigation you throughout different views I think. Maybe because it's a WebView, hmm.

Comment: I'm Prety sure it uses a fragement mananager and just changes the fragment that is in the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the structure you're after with the actionbar.. For starters the drop down list that goes next to your apps icon if you look in the official Android docs isn't implemented yet.

You could implement a menu like how the Facebook app works:

[App with Facebook app navigation style](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/134112/app-with-facebook-app-navigation-style)

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for pointing this out and for the link.
But what exactly do you mean with the dropdown list isnt implemented yet? I thought the actionbar is kind of a dropdown menu?

Comment: Not really, take a look at the Action bar spec for native Android: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html. There's quite a lot that isn't implemented, the dropdown menu and search are some that's missing