# Android navigation style- drop down menu

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, navigation, styles

I wanna use the navigation style in my android project. Style is drop down menu so action bar spinner menu. but it isn't like user input one spinner. I wanna use spinner in menu. But i have no idea. i searched something but they didn't work. so any tutorial about that will be very good.

Thanks to much

edit: [Drop Down Menu on Action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376101/drop-down-menu-on-action-bar) in this picture,there is a maps, and it has a map,local,navigation,check in etc. i wanna like this one. i wanna select local (for this picture) show something but select navigation show something else

Comment: I'm unclear on what you're trying to do. Can you show some image examples?

Comment: i added something about my questions. thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer with the solution. If this was what you were looking for please mark my answer as accepted. Much appreciated. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to use an Actionbar spinner dropdown for this.

AndroidHive has an EXCELLENT write up on all things actionbars. I've grabbed the bit that you're looking for, but if you want to read the full article, **[Click Here.](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/)**

**This is the result:**

[image]

**Here is the code:**

MainActivity.java

```
package info.androidhive.actionbar;

import info.androidhive.actionbar.model.SpinnerNavItem;
import info.androidhive.info.actionbar.adapter.TitleNavigationAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.SearchView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener{

    // action bar
    private ActionBar actionBar;

    // Title navigation Spinner data
    private ArrayList<SpinnerNavItem> navSpinner;

    // Navigation adapter
    private TitleNavigationAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        actionBar = getActionBar();

        // Hide the action bar title
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        // Enabling Spinner dropdown navigation
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

        // Spinner title navigation data
        navSpinner = new ArrayList<SpinnerNavItem>();
        navSpinner.add(new SpinnerNavItem("Local", R.drawable.ic_location));
        navSpinner.add(new SpinnerNavItem("My Places", R.drawable.ic_my_places));
        navSpinner.add(new SpinnerNavItem("Checkins", R.drawable.ic_checkin));
        navSpinner.add(new SpinnerNavItem("Latitude", R.drawable.ic_latitude));     

        // title drop down adapter
        adapter = new TitleNavigationAdapter(getApplicationContext(), navSpinner);

        // assigning the spinner navigation     
        actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    ....
    }

    /**
     * On selecting action bar icons
     * */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    ...
    }

    /**
     * Actionbar navigation item select listener
     * */
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
    // Action to be taken after selecting a spinner item
        return false;
    }
}
```