# Adding submenu for menuitem

Tags: android

I want to create notification list like Facebook:

[image]

I don't know its name, I have searched the web and I can't find it, so I moved to submenu.

I have a flowing menu item

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_bookinglist"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/tblbooking_notification"
    android:icon="@drawable/notify_tablebooking"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Booking List"/>
```

How can I add SubMenu for this item dynamically? **Note:** this menuitem has actionlayout, from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042958/android-adding-a-submenu-to-a-menuitem-where-is-addsubmenu) question To create submenu we have to create menu also dynamically, if so how to set `actionLayout` for dynamically created `MenuItem`?

My requirement is create notification list like that image.

Comment: This is a custom view, you won't find it on google...

Comment: Okay, How can you add list like this to MenuItem?

Comment: this question is a duplicate. Search for DropDown menu : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376101/drop-down-menu-on-action-bar

Comment: check this : http://sunil-android.blogspot.com/2013/09/custom-listview-alertdialog-with-filter.html

Comment: I need Notification list, not listview,