# How to include a dropdown menu to Android Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to include a drop down menu to android action bar like in the Google Maps app. I don not want to include any third party libraries such as actionbarsherlock since I believe we can do this using android SDK.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drop Down Menu on Action bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376101/drop-down-menu-on-action-bar)

Comment: Why did you create a same question with same images listed in link above?

Comment: You're so confident! Why dint you try anything yet then ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a toolbar from the AppCompat library to act as your actionbar and then add a `spinner` within the toolbar because toolbar acts like a regular layout where you can add views within it.

here is a sample:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/triple_height_toolbar"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >

  <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/planets_spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And finding the spinner within the toolbar is calling the `findViewById` within the toolbar.

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
Spinnertitle = (Spinner)toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
```

[Link Here](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/) is how to add a toolbar in your application

Comment: Adding Toolbar as an `ActionBar` requires call of `setSupportActionBar()` where you just pass toolbar instance as its argument.